# Why insert statement's time cost ranges so big?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, innodb, jdbctemplate

I want to import Wikipedia Database. [Wikipedia Dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/zhwiki/20170720/)

I have changed some Innodb settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_file_size=8G
innodb_log_buffer_size=512M
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
max_allowed_packet=256M
```

[image]

This picture shows that every single Sql statement's time cost.

The sql statement is like this: Insert into `templatelinks` value(...),(...),(...),(...)... Every single sql statement's size is 1MB.

**Why the 1300th to 1400th sql costs so much time?**

More Information:

1. During this period, this table's size is almost 9GB, and table rows is 40million.
2. I use Spring JdbcTemplate to execute sql statement
3. My Computer's Memory is 8G and database is stored in HDD.

core code:

```
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(mDatasour);

    while (it.hasNext()){
        jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; ");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; ");
        String line=it.nextLine();
        if(line==null||line.length()==0){
            continue;
        }
        jdbcTemplate.execute(line);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("commit;");
```

[image: table columns]

[image: table index details]

Comment: are you indexing your table?

Comment: Perhaps your server got busy with something else? Since you're doing mass insert, performance bottleneck is likely the disk, so if some background process on the server started using the disk (e.g. virus scan), then insert performance would slow to a crawl, since disk arm is now trying to be in two places at the same time.

Comment: @Muhammad ，I have add more information.

Comment: @Andreas ,It's run on my PC. Nothing else happens.

Comment: So you are *absolutely sure* there is no background Operating System job that began using the disk at that time? That would be pretty amazing, being sure about that, given the insane number of background jobs found in an OS like Windows.

Comment: How many times have you run this test? In general, there are n factors that can impact that, with n being much bigger than you imagine. For example, how much is your hdd fragmented ? Was your Antivirus turned on or off? Was any update happening in the background? Which Windows are you using? Are there any screensaver? Did you move your mouse?

Answer (score 1):

**Optimize code**

Pull the constant stuff out of the loop.  Hote the use of autocommit to avoid need to issue `COMMIT`.

```
jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setAutoCommit(true); -- Note
jdbcTemplate.execute("SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; ");
jdbcTemplate.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; ");
while (it.hasNext()){
    String line=it.nextLine();
    if(line==null||line.length()==0){
        continue;
    }
    jdbcTemplate.execute(line);
}
```

**Smaller chunks**

Stop building line at either 1000 rows or 1MB, whichever is smaller.  Beyond that, you are well into diminishing returns, and stressing the undo log.

**Get rid of redundant UNIQUE**

Drop `UNIQUE(from, namespace, title)` is is redundant with the `PRIMARY KEY` which has the identical list of columns.  This will cut back on the insert effort because all unique index must be checked during the `INSERT`.

**Change buffering**

Read about "Change buffering".  It is essentially a delayed (and optimized) writing of non-unique indexes, of which you seem to have two.  At some point during the massive insertions, the Change buffer gets full and must be flushed.  This flushing is done in the background, so I cannot explain the severity of the spikes.

I suspect the change buffer got too backlogged after about 1/3 of the table was loaded, and this caused the hiccups.

**Order of incoming rows**

Other things to consider...  What order were the rows being written?  If they were being written in PK order, then very little I/O is needed to do each INSERT into the PK (and data) (and the redundant UNIQUE index).  Your graph seems to show this by the I/O being so low for a long time at the beginning.

However, the secondary indexes (handled through the Change buffer) are probably quite random.  (I don't know what `from` refers to.)  This leads to a lot of "read-modify-write" actions to update the index blocks for the two secondary indexes.

Since the PK+data does not need the buffer_pool much, but the secondary indexes do, consider tweaking `innodb_change_buffer_max_size`, which defaults to "25% of the buffer_pool being set aside for the change buffer".

**Flushing to disk**

Another issue:  Writes to the PK+data do not need to be flushed to disk until exceeding "innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct - defaults to 90% of buffer_pool".  Again, this is consistent with the low I/O early on.

Learn about those two settings, play around with them, then write a blog post.  You will become the expert on such.

Answer (score 1):

With innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G, after 25% is set aside for innodb_change_buffer_max_size, your effective pool size is 3G.

Your innodb_io_capacity and innodb_io_capacity_max could likely be raised to take advantage of today's HDD capacity.  sqlio.exe download from Microsoft can help you determine your limits for 16384 (MySQL) data block size for your HDD.

Adding RAM would be in your best interest for keeping data in memory longer.